# In Sikuli, can we search an image in UI webpage with a word/text that is displayed in the image content?

Tags: selenium, automation, sikuli, sikuli-script, sikuli-x

I am using Serenity with Selenium to automate a webpage having images (list of large thumbnails). I am checking if there is an option to search in the UI with a text/word that is displayed in the image content.

For example: I want to find if the image exists in the UI having the text. 
I want to find if the image exists in screen having this word "Pexels".

[image: Examle image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it does not matter for Sikuli whether that's a printed text or a part of an image. What you have to take into account though is the enclosing region you are going to look for this text in as this might affect the result you are getting. Internally Sikuli is using Tesseract OCR which can be sensitive to text placement within a region. So if you see you are getting inconsistent results, first of all make sure what is actually being detected within the selected region and then try to change it to focus on the specific area of the test if possible.